# Lumen does not detect https behind a reverse proxy

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, lumen

I have a Lumen API behind a reverse proxy in a  docker container that only responds on port 80. So the client requests a certain domain https://xyz.ab/api/endpoint and everything works fine.

But if you want to use `Request->secure()` to check if you are on http or https lumen returns false (= http) and generates wrong urls.

I tried to use `URL::forceScheme("https");` to tell lumen to use https anyways but lumen still insists on http.

I do not want to install a certificate inside my container only to make lumen believe in https.

Is there a place where I can configure lumen globally to use https instead of http?

Thank you.

Comment: For Laravel there's a trustedproxies.php config file, not sure how Lumen handles it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, PtrTon. That was exactly the right answer. Lumen uses `Illumintae\Http\Request` which extends `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation` which includes the `setTrustedProxies` method.

So what I basically had to do, was:

1. Create a middleware that sets trusted proxies.
2. Create a config file with my trusted proxies.
3. Configure my Reverse Proxy to forward the correct headers, which are:

   - X_FORWARDED_PROTO=https
   - X_FORWARDED_HOST={HTTP_HOST}
   - X_FORWARDED_FOR{HTTP_CLIENT_IP}
   - X_FORWARDED_PORT={SERVER_PORT}

For ssl it is enough to add X_FORWARDED_PROTO=https or X_FORWARDED_PORT=443 because these are the values that the secure() method is looking for. As soon as you add them and tell lumen to trust the proxy secure() returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a detailed implementation for those who are not so familiar with Lumen.

1. Create a middleware(`TrustedProxiesMiddleware`) under App\Http\Middleware.

   ```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class TrustedProxiesMiddleware
    {

        /**
         *  use 0.0.0.0/0 if you trust any proxy, otherwise replace it with your proxy ips
         * 
         * @var string[]
         */
        protected $trustedProxies = [
            '0.0.0.0/0'
        ];

        public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next){
            Request::setTrustedProxies($this->trustedProxies);
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
   ```
2. In `bootstrap/app.php` file, add this middleware:

   ```
    $app->middleware([
        //other middlewares........
        App\Http\Middleware\TrustedProxiesMiddleware::class
    ]);
   ```
3. Make sure your proxy sends `X-FORWARDED-PROTO` header to backend servers